# How ignore NULL entries on a datagridview

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, null

I've got a piece of code that reads integers and date values from a `datagridview`. Some of the `k` values have null entries in and i'm trying to get the app to ignore those cells but I'm not having any luck. The error pops up on the line
`j = datediff....`

I've tried using an the if statement

`If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(k).Value IsNot Nothing Then`
but it still produces an error that tells me it can't convert `DBNull` entries to `date`.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong so any help would be appreciated.

```
    For k = 8 To 52 Step 2

        Dim j As Integer

        If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(k).Value IsNot Nothing Then

            j = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(k).Value, DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(k - 2).Value)

            If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(k + 1).Value = 0 Then

                If j > 7 Then
                    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(k - 1).Value = 6
                Else
                End If
            Else
            End If
        End If

    Next k
```

Comment: Because `Nothing` is not `DbNull`. Add comparison for `DbNull.Value` to the condition

Comment: would an if statement such as `If Not IsDBNull(k) then...` be effective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Option Strict On` in your project or file if you want get more help in recognising possible errors in compile time.

- `Nothing` and `DbNull` is not same.
- `Nothing` is default value of the type
- `DbNull` us type which represents database `NULL` value.
- Only `DbNull.Value` is comparable.

```vb
For k = 8 To 52 Step 2
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    If row.Cells(k).Value Is DBNull.Value Or row.Cells(k).Value Is Nothing Then Continue For

    Dim firstDate As Date = DirectCast(row.Cells(k).Value, Date)
    Dim secondDate As Date = DirectCast(row.Cells(k - 2).Value, Date)
    Dim difference As TimeSpan = firstDate - secondData

    If difference.Days > 7 AndAlso row.Cells(k + 1).Value = 0 Then
        row.Cells(k - 1).Value = 6
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I now understand the difference between nothing and DBNull. I've tried putting your code in but an error pops up at the line `If Row.Cells(k).Value = DBNull.value Then Continue For` saying: Operator '=' is not defined for type 'Date' and type 'DBNull'. Any suggestions?

Comment: `DataGridVIewCell.Value` returns value of type `object` so use `Is` keyword instead of `=`

Comment: Thanks that part is working now. The error now pops up for `dim firstdate as date...` line and says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I changed the code back to my original `j = ...` and the applications accepts it but the code doesn't do anything

Comment: Don't worry @Fabio I've fixed it by swapping the line `If Row.Cells(k).Value s DBNull.value Then Continue For` to `If row.Cells(k).Value Is DBNull.Value Or row.Cells(k).Value Is Nothing Then Continue For`. Thanks for your help and i will be accepting your answer